# XSLT Element Value from MAP

Tags: xslt

This is my school home work and can't figure it out myself.

I need to reformat an XML file from the input source to output XML using Transformation.

My input source has many tags (elements).

I have tags like this:

```
<tag>
 <name>DOB</name>
 <value>XX/XX/XX</value>
</tag>
<tag>
 <name>Address</name>
 <value>123 Main St.</value>
</tag>
```

and I need to transform these to

```
<DOB>xx/xx/xx</DOB>
<Address>123 Main St.</Address>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? It would be easier to help you learn if we knew exactly where you were getting stuck.

Comment: Since you are a beginner, and also new to StackExchange, you might want to visit the [help], take the [tour] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.  Requests for homework help must show a significant amount of effort on your part to solve the problem.  If you are really lost you should be talking to your professor.

Comment: well, i made all other parts working except this one. and I am stuck few days to resolve this. I can't find any thing close solution from this site. This is small part of the problem that I can't find any solution. My teacher said use conditional but I don't think that is elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My teacher said use conditional but I don't think that is elegant way
>   to do it.

No, it's not. And what exactly would the *condition* be? You should try:

```
<xsl:template match="tag">
    <xsl:element name="{name}">
        <xsl:value-of select="value" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this will fail if the contents of `name` are not a valid XML name.

Comment: This is great thank you. I was not able to get {name} before that part was not working but now with{} it is working fine. Thanks.